# Why didn't the client folder from my project get uploaded on gitHub?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, repository

I wanted to upload a project on github repository so I can send it to my instructor and it’s my first time. All the folders’ content got uploaded except client folder and its icon looks different. Why did that happen?

I used these commands in the terminal

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ git remote add origin remote repository URL
$ git remote -v
$ git push -u origin master
```

Edit: my client folder is a reactjs app

Comment: is you there anything inside your '/client' folder?

Comment: "*its icon looks different*" — I suspect a submodule or a subrepository here.

Comment: Could you please post what difference in icons you are observing and add them to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to be a bit more specific. 
One possible answer: There is a .gitignore file (hidden file) that prevents the client folder from being pushed. 
Another: You simply didn't stage the client folder. Try *git add ./client* and then commit and push again.

Comment: Yes I think there is hidden file. I tried copying the files one by one in another folder and they got pushed to github. Now for my old folder, how can I find this hidden file and remove it in the future. I think this hidden file is because my client folder is a react app. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, Gatsby had created a .git folder in client which prevented it from being added to the repo.

`rm -rf client/.git`

Comment: Same for me. I used `create-react-app` only.

Answer (score 1):

After doing `git add .` check if the files are staged inside the client folder by doing `git status`.It may be the problem of .gitignore file which ignores specific files that are not to be committed. If client is not on .gitignore the files inside it should be staged. And if it is not staged after doing `git add .` you can see the individual files that are not staged after doing `git status` and individually add the files to staging area.